# What is difference between first while loop and second while loop?

Tags: java, io

what is difference between 1st and 2nd loop;

```
package standard;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class practice {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
        {
    FileInputStream f=new FileInputStream("F:\\a.txt");
```

its 1st while loop which has a int in it

```
    int s;
    while((s=f.read())!=-1)
    {
        System.out.print((char)s);
    }
```

this is 2nd while loop

```
    while(f.read()!=-1)
        {
        System.out.print((char)f.read());
        }
     }



}
```

Comment: in the second loop you are reading 2 times for an iteration, you will display only the half of what you read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first while loop reads a byte into a variable in the loop's condition and checks that's it's not equal to -1, and then prints that variable in the loop body.

The second while loop reads a byte, checks that it's not equal to -1, and then reads the next byte in the loop's body and prints it.

Therefore the first loop prints the entire file while the second loop prints half the bytes of the file.

Comment: but f.read() returns an int right?then why im getting half of the file only?

Comment: @AbhishekVishwakarma in `while(f.read()!=-1)` you are not printing the int returned by `f.read()`. Inside the loop you are calling f.read() again, which returns a different value.

Answer (score 0):

In first loop you are saving result of `f.read()` into s variable and than doing `System.out.println()` of the result.

In second you do not saving result of first `f.read()` and doing `System.out.println()` only for every second bite in file

Answer (score 0):

About the first `while loop` you are reading inside from the `while loop` condition and assign it into variable `s` and you are `type casting` that to a char and printing it.

But in the second `while loop` you are reading twice once in the `while loop` condition and second while you are printing and `type casting` it to `char` and printing it. In the second case you will print only the second character each iteration. If you have input like `abcd` in the first `while loop` it will print `abcd` but in the second while loop it will print only `bd`.

Common in both `while loop` condition is you are checking  for `-1` to break the loop.